# Why this code was not return at label in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Why this code does not return from `ints2.forEach` but will output `level 1 xx ====` every time? 
And there is not difference when I set the label `let@` to `ints2.forEach`.

```
fun foo() {
    val ints = Array(5, {i->i})
    ints.forEach let@ {
        println("level 1 $it ====")
        val ints2 = Array(3, {i->i})
        ints2.forEach {
            if (it == 2) return@let
            println("level 2 $it")
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    foo()
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the expected output? I didn't understand your question completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why this code does not return from ints.forEach and will output "level 1 xx ====" many times?

By returning to a label (`@let` in your case), it returns only from the lambda expression inside `forEach`. Therefore your `foo()` is equivalent to below code (using anonymous function instead of labels). That's why `forEach` block will still be executed for each value in the array. You can find more details [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html).

```
fun foo() {
    val ints = Array(5, {i->i})
    ints.forEach(fun(it: Int) {
        println("level 1 $it ====")
        val ints2 = Array(3, {i->i})
        ints2.forEach {
            if (it == 2) return
            println("level 2 $it")
        }
    })
}
```

> And there is not difference when I set the label "let@" to
>   ints2.forEach.

Same reason as above. By settng `@let` label to `ints2.forEach`, this inner `forEach` block is still executed twice before `it == 2`.